# Remove autogenerated HTML in typo3

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.x

Trying to get into typo3; unfortunately the docs aren't really helpful for me. After creating a backend-layout I am trying to output multiple columns.

Right now I'm getting the following output:

```
<div id="c23" class="frame frame-default frame-type-text frame-layout-0">
    <a id="c30"></a>
    <header>
        <h2 class="">Title</h2>
    </header>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed …</p>
</div>
```

I'd like to have the output without any extra elements, like this:

```
<h2>Title</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed …</p>
```

What is the correct way to get the "correct" output in typoscript?

Comment: Which TYPO3 version do you use and do you have installed extension fluid_styled_content or css_styled_content?

Comment: `8.7.4` is the version I'm using. `css_styles_content` was installed by default but isn't activated, `fluid_styled_content` is installed and active.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such HTML attributes comming from EXT:fluid_styled_content (*/typo3/sysext/fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private/Layouts/Default.html*).
To adapt this and all other files, you should make a copy of folders Templates, Partials, Layouts from */typo3/sysext/fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private*, define them via typoscript constants as new paths:

```
styles.templates {
    templateRootPath = [PATH/TO/YOUR/FOLDER/Templates]
    partialRootPath = [PATH/TO/YOUR/FOLDER/Partials]
    layoutRootPath = [PATH/TO/YOUR/FOLDER/Layouts]
}
```

and adpat them for your needs, especially */PATH/TO/YOUR/FOLDER/Layouts/Default.html*
This is best done in a recommended own sitepackage. You could use https://sitepackagebuilder.com/new/ to start with.

Comment: Set up everything with the sitepackage and works perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If is TYPO3 7.6

Yo need to override boostrap-package Layouts/ContentElements/Default.html

because there are created that classes and from that files remove wrapper
div id="c{data.uid}" class="frame frame-type-{data.CType} frame-layout-{data.layout} {sectionClass}"

Only wrapper!

Answer (score 1):

with FSC (fluid_styled_content) all your markup is in fluid-templates, which you can override.
go to your server and copy files from `(webroot)/typo3/sysext/fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private/` + `Layouts/` and/or `Partials/` and/or `Templates/`.
In typoscript setup you need to define additional pathes to your variants.

Don't copy all files, but copy only those you modify.
In your case you probably need to modify the Layouts/* and Partials/*header*.